# Drawing very small shapes (size in µm) with python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create "L" shapes black and white structure on a 20x20 mm figure. Each L shape width and length are defined as uw, ul, lw and ll (see code). A sper my understanding matplotlib works with points per inch (PPI) of 72 and with linewidth of 1, the shape will be 1/72 inch wide. I cannot understand how I can make these figures big enough to be visible when I use plt.show() and save them in the size I want (i.e. 20x20 mm page and each L with their exact shape size with high DPI so that I can view it when I open the saved figure). My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
uw = 20e-6  #upper width in meters
ul = 100e-6 #upper length in meters
lw = 20e-6  #lower width in meters
ll = 100e-6 #lower length in meters
w_space = 50e-6 #width spacing for subplots
h_space = 50e-6 #height spacing for subplots
N = 40

coord = [[0,0], [ll,0], [ll,lw], [uw,lw], [uw,ul], [0,ul]]
coord.append(coord[0]) #repeat the first point to create a 'closed loop'
xs, ys = zip(*coord) #create lists of x and y values

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(0.1, 0.1), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k') #figsize cannot be chosen below 0.1
for i in range(N):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(5,10,i+1)
    ax.fill(xs,ys,'k',linewidth=1)
    plt.axis('off')
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = w_space, hspace = h_space)
plt.savefig('screenshots/L_shape.png' ,bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0, dpi=10000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: DPI is relevant for the output IF you chose a rasterized output, but NOT for the axes limits! So you can scale your axes completely independent from the DPI.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly clear. Do you not see the L shapes in the output figure?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Yes, I want to see the figure when I run plt.show() to check how teh final image would be and also I want to save it with figure size of 20x20 mm with the actual dimensions of L shapes.

Comment: Given that the "size" of a figure is irrelevant for raster images, I do not understand the "20x20 mm" used here.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding but I though figsize defines the final image in inches. I wanted to sav final image 20 x 20 mm (i.e w=h=20mm/25.4 = 0.78 inches). This 0.78 inches image should have L shapes with their specified size in micro-meters  (in the saved figure).

Comment: Creating a png image means that you create a bunch of pixels. E.g. You may get a 200x200 pixel image by creating a figure of size 1 inch with a dpi of 200, or a figure of 2 inch with dpi of 100 or a figure of 4 inch with dpi 50 etc. That seems to be quite independent of the units you use in the axes. You could equally use kilometers as units.

Comment: Oh O.K. I got it now. for 1x1 inch image, I can scale x and y axis to be 1 inch and then when I plot something there it will be based on their exact size. for example: point (0.5, 0.5 inch) would exactly in the center of the 1x1 inch image.